# Converting a list of lists into a dataframe in R. I need the names of the list of lists as columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I have a list of lists:

```
list <- list(list(1,"a",2), list(3,"b",4,5), list(6,"c"))
```

I do not know how to show it, but each list of list's names are similar:[image of the names of the list of lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLHaw.png)

such that 1 from the *first* list of lists maps to "id", "a" maps to "code_name", and 2 maps to "project".

the 4th element in the *second* list has another name (cannot show it in the snapshot due to sensitivity), and the number 5 maps to it.

I need a df where the names are the columns and thus the elements in the *first* list (i.e 1, "a", and 2) becomes the first row.

And then the elements in the *second* list (i.e 3,"b",4,5) becomes the second row.

I have tried:

```
df <- as.data.frame(sapply(list, unlist))
```

and it error was:

> Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
>     arguments imply differing number of rows: 3, 4, 2

I have tried:

```
df <- as.data.frame(list[1])
```

And that was somewhat what i needed but then i need the rest of the rows.

Thanks in advance, I am very new to R but I know this is a very simple manipulation yet i just can't get it.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague, but what I interpreted is that you need to create a consolidated data.frame out of your nested lists. I would do this in two steps:

1. convert each list to a data.frame, similar to what you did
2. `rbind` these data.frames together under the assumption that the columns should line up...this is why I gave them consistent names

I use `rbindlist` from package `data.table` since it has a nice `fill` argument.

Here's the solution:

```r
library(data.table)
my_list <- list(list(1,"a",2), list(3,"b",4,5), list(6,"c"))
my_list <- lapply(my_list, function(x){
  dat <- as.data.frame(x)
  names(dat) <- paste0("X", 1:ncol(dat))
  return(dat)
})
df <- rbindlist(my_list, fill = TRUE)
df
#>    X1 X2 X3 X4
#> 1:  1  a  2 NA
#> 2:  3  b  4  5
#> 3:  6  c NA NA
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>